# Reference paper for gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is [Design and use paradigms for gazebo, an open-source multi-robot simulator](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3583267314289704660&hl=en&as_sdt=0,41) (N Koenig, A Howard - Intelligent Robots and Systems, 2004) still the canonical reference for Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3240/reference-paper-for-gazebo/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-06-17**:
Not really canonical, but quite a recent one from ICRA'13 - N. Koenig and J. Hsu, “The many faces of simulation: Use cases for a general purpose simulator,” in ICRA’13 Workshop on Developments of Simulation Tools for Robotics & Biomechanics, 2013. Not sure will it be available online at any point since workshop papers tend to be not included to indices like IEEEXplore. May be Nate or John will upload it later.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-06-17**:
P.S. The link you have provided is broken, looks like a missed `http://`.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-06-18**:
sorry about that, corrected.

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2019-01-09**:
It is not a good idea to cite a paper that is not available to read. It is not a good practice to cite a paper just for the sake of citation. Citation is done to inform reader about where to find more information on said sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The 2004 IROS paper is the right one. They didn't write a paper for the ICRA'13 workshop; just an abstract and then the talk.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-06-18**:
Apparently they did write something for ICRA :) You can find it on the conference's CD/USB titled "ICRA'13 Workshops and Tutorials Proceedings". Although it has only 2 pages, there are title, abstract, 5 sections and references. So looks like a paper to me. Again I am not clear about its official status, i.e. can it be treated as a publication.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-06-18**:
I asked Nate, and he said they submitted a 2 page abstract for the ICRA workshop. He also said that the 2004 IROS paper is the right one to reference.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thanks for clarifying!

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2014-01-29**:
Any news on this? Unfortunately, 2004 paper is bit out of date...